# Transform Hough_Circles into a heatmap using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, scikit-learn, visualization

I'm using Hough Circles algorithm to detect circles in an image. Some circles ovelap while others don't. I need to visualize the over lapping area with a high probability and non overlapping areas with low probability with some indicator(As a heat map). How to achive this and is there a specific term for this?

I need this :[image]

What I get is this :
[image]

```
def display_image(flag=0, frame=None):
# flag 0 - read image from path, flag 1 - image is passed
img = None
cimg = None

if (flag == 0):
    # cv2.imread(img_path, 0) ; 0 - gray image
    img = cv2.imread(img_path, 0)
else:
    img = frame
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

img = cv2.medianBlur(img, 5)
img = cv2.resize(img, (int(img.shape[1]/2), int(img.shape[0]/2)))
cimg = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

circles = cv2.HoughCircles(
    img, method=cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, dp=1, minDist=5, param1=75, param2=30, minRadius=60, maxRadius=100)
    # img, method=cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, dp=1, minDist=5, param1=75, param2=30, minRadius=40, maxRadius=100)

#np.around() > EVENLY round to the given number of decimals.
#np.unit16 > Unsigned integer (0 to 65535)
circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))

for i in circles[0, :]:
    # draw the outer circle
    cv2.circle(cimg, (i[0], i[1]), i[2], (0, 255, 0), -1)
    # draw the center of the circle
    cv2.circle(cimg, (i[0], i[1]), 2, (0, 0, 255), 3)

if (flag == 0):
    #single image
    cv2.imshow('detected circles', cimg)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
else:
    return cimg
```

Comment: It's always useful to put images you are using and what code/outputs you have so far. It will help those on this website to answer you better.

Comment: Also, you have tagged it with both `matlab` and `python`. You should only tag it with the tag that represent the language your problem is in. If you using both languages, then that is two separate questions. Please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) , [Minimum Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update your question accordingly.

Comment: I updated my question. Hope you guys have a solution.

Comment: Where is your input image? Your code is not a Minimum Verifiable Example. It never calls display_image. Please provide your input and code that can be used by others to reproduce your results. Please read the help section of this forum for how to ask a good question and other related topics.

Answer (score 0):

```
# transparency factor
tr = 0.3
for i in circles[0, :]:
    # copy cimg
    temp_img = cimg.copy()
    # draw circle
    cv2.circle(temp_img, (i[0], i[1]), i[2], (255, 255, 255), -1)
    # blend to get transparency
    cimg = np.uint8(np.float64(cimg)*tr + np.float64(temp_img)*(1-tr))
```